# url setting in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to set URL because I am using AJAX get for all the processes.
When I login in to the site it must say 
Home>PortalUser

When i click a menu say (Reseller) it should say Home/PortalUser/Reseller.
then when i click a sub menu of reseller say Settings URL should be like this

Home/PortalUser/Reseller/Settings.

From this page i click the menu Reseller againg, then the URL should be like this
Home/PortalUser/Reseller

How can I set this. I Am new to MVC , so pardon me if this is a silly question. Thanks in advance

Arjun

Comment: What you mean? did you want to setup a breadcrumb?

Comment: like a breadcrumb, but instead i need URL of browser to look like it. As i said am using AJAX and so it wont affect browser url. All i need to do is update the url based on pages

Answer (score 1):

You need to define new route configuration in your Global.asax for this specific controller like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PortalUserRouter", 
        url: "Home/PortalUser/{controller}/{Action}/{id}", 
        defaults: new { controller = "Reseller", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    );
}
```

Assuming your controller is Reseller.

Comment: this will create a breadcrumb rt? what i want is to set the browser URL

Comment: ah I see, I'm confused with your questions.

Comment: My apologies.. So can you help me out??

Comment: Well, i already make an edit 4 hours ago on my post, you can check it out.

Comment: hi reptildarat, sorry for the late response. i was out of town. Let me try this & will get back to you

Comment: whoops, typo..i don't know what i'm thinking when i write those. you can just specify withoute parameter like the "default" route.

Comment: Hi Hi.. Sure thing. but can you tell me what's the difference between Httpmaproute and the maproute

Comment: you mean MapHttpRoute? it's do the same thing, MapHttpRoute it's the old one.

Comment: `routes.MapRoute(
      name: "BrowserURL",
      url: "Home/PortalUser/{controller}/{Action}/{id}/{companytype}/{companyId}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Portaluser", action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional,companytype = UrlParameter.Optional, companyid = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );`

Comment: "<a onclick=\"ajaxGet3('Reseller','Details','" + Convert.ToInt32(Drd.Uboss.Framework.CompanyType.Reseller) + "','" + item["Id"] + "','" + item["Id"] + "')\" class='aover'>" + item["Name"].ToString() + " </a>" : item["Name"].ToString() + strDateInfo;

Comment: will this [  url: "Home/PortalUser/{controller}/{Action}/{id} ] in anyway affect browser url? i am using AJAX

Comment: of course, now the controller will expect "portaluser" first before the name of the controller.

Comment: can i ask a doubt? when i give the url as Home/PortalUser/{controller}/{action}/{id} the browser url will be like Home/portalUser/Reseller/Details/580? In my ajax method do i have to hard core the first part i.e Home/PortalUser?

Comment: Yep, it will be like that. btw, if your controller is PortalUser, then you should specify that like this: "Home/{controller}/Reseller/{action}/{id}"

Comment: but it didn't reflect in the url :(, even though i gave like this in global asax  
            routes.MapRoute(name: "BrowserURL", url: "Home/PortalUser/{controller}/{action}/{companytype}/{companyId}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Portaluser", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, companytype = UrlParameter.Optional, companyid = UrlParameter.Optional }
                          );

Comment: i am facing the problem specified here [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1673375.aspx)

Comment: what version asp mvc that you use? check on folder app_start -> RouteConfig, place your new route before the default one.

Comment: mvc 4.
 routes.MapRoute(
                                name: "BrowserURL", 
                                url: "Home/PortalUser/{controller}/{action}/{companytype}/{companyId}/{id}",
                                defaults: new { controller = "Portaluser", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, companytype = UrlParameter.Optional, companyid = UrlParameter.Optional }
                            );  this is the first route in my class

Comment: y i have to remove controller? Then its ajax request, just to remind you : )

Comment: you already define the controller name with "home/portaluser", if you add it again it will be "home/portaluser/portaluser", that's why i told you to do: "home/{controller}/{action}"

Comment: And try to access it use fiddler or this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm

Comment: But dude, home portal user is the default url , my controller is reseller, action is getdetails and id is say 250. the controller can change depending upon the pages taken.

Comment: well i found a way to handle it in javascript , once the call is success (ajax) i reset the url using controller/action/id and set it as  window.location.pathname if not HTML 5 unsupported browser else window.history.pushState({ "html": data.html, "pageTitle": data.pageTitle }, "", urlPath);